# How to upload large github repository more than 2GB file with vs code

Tags: github, github-pages

I need to upload my file on github repository, The file is more than 2GB and I am unable to upload my file on github repository using vscode terminal.
When I try to commit the file it says,

**Git: warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in "pathname" Learning/debug.log**

The file contain html, css, js, audio, video , img etc with full year code of 2019. need to upload those file on github repository, I was tried but not able need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [**What is my disk quota?**](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/what-is-my-disk-quota)
>
> File and repository size limitations
>
> We recommend repositories be kept under 1GB each. Repositories have a hard limit of 100GB. If you reach 75GB you'll receive a warning from Git in your terminal when you push. This limit is easy to stay within if large files are kept out of the repository. If your repository exceeds 1GB, you might receive a polite email from GitHub Support requesting that you reduce the size of the repository to bring it back down.
>
> In addition, **we place a strict limit of files exceeding 100 MB in size**. For more information, see "[Working with large files.](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files)"